# distribute crystal report to my customers

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, distribution, vendor

how to distribute crystal reports to my customers? actually , i have a software built on c#.net and sql server as database and i have used crystal reports for reporting. now i want that when i give my software to my customers then its obvious that the crystal reports would also be given . so how to do this? do i have to download crystal reports on the customers PCs or else? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download and install [**Crystal Report Runtime**](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp) according to Visual Studio version your application is made with and the type of destination PC (32 or 64bit).
Then install it manually on every PC or programmatically using a setup.

Comment: sir, if i add a setup module in my winform application then add files into it, then will it work, which files to add?

Comment: @sqlchild: you must include the correct Framework(the one you compiled your app with), Crystal Report Runtime, your exe and all DLLs referenced from your application.
For CR: which version did you use? If you're compiling with VS2010 propbably you're using Crystal Report 13: donwload 32 and 64bit, include them in your setup and install it according to target OS.

Comment: so, after doing the process you told , what steps would i have to do on my customer's PC. i would paste my software exe on his PC . and execute it. what else? will CR be automatically installed on running the exe of my application?

Comment: @sqlchild: you have to use CR as a prerequisite in your setup, so that if it's not installed, it will be. That's all.
If you want you can manually run CR setup inside your setup and wait until it's finished.

Comment: sir, so if i do this, i won't need to install Runtime on my customer's pc

Comment: or are you talking about the Runtime itself. that i have to select the Runtime files in the Setup Module. i mean to say that if i include the CR Runtime in the Setup Module then i won't need to install CR Runtime on my customer's PC

Comment: @Marco : also, will i not need any licence? as i would give the reports generated from it and add the reports in my software and install my software on my customer PCs

Comment: @sqlchild: you have to include CR runtime in your setup and you MUST install it into customer's PC. If you're using Visual Studio Professional, probably you have a free license for CR Visual Studio Edition (it's not the righr name, but just to let you understand) that you can freely redistribute.
During your setup you must install CR runtime if you want to open/view/print reports you created (and distributed with) in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a crystal reports runtime on each client machine - having used crystal you should find somewhere in its directories the runtime installer to include in the package